# SpeechRecognizer not detecting end of speech on jelly bean

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Am using `SpeechRecognizer` directly and I have implemented custom `RecognitionListener`. Speech recognition works fine on android other than **jelly bean**. On jelly bean Recognizer is not able to detect end of speech.

My code is as below

```
 speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new CustomListener());  
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                    "com.somemodule");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
```

What am I missing? 
I found one more person reporting the issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/pD-HTG-VOlM)  but no one has provided the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that, SpeechRecognizer does not work on certain network. In my case it never worked when i tried to access internet via Intranet but worked on 3G network/ public internet.

Similarly built-in voice search failed on Intranet